# SQL Query to get distinct values from a table and the difference between ordered rows

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a real time data table with time stamps for different data points
Time_stamp, UID, Parameter1, Parameter2, ....

I have 400 UIDs so each time_stamp is repeated 400 times

I want to write a query that uses this table to check if the real time data flow to the SQL database is working as expected - new timestamp every 5 minute should be available

For this what I usually do is query the DISTINCT values of time_stamp in the table and order descending - do a visual inspection and copy to excel to calculate the difference in minutes between subsequent distinct time_stamp

Any difference over 5 min means I have a problem. I am trying to figure out how I can do something similar in SQL, maybe get a table that looks like this. Tried to use LEAD and DISTINCT together but could not write the code myself, im just getting started on SQL

Time_stamp, LEAD over last timestamp

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does your system works by this way: each 5 minutes it accepts 400 rows then did nothing 5 minites then accepts another 400 rows.. and so on?

Comment: Do you need to check that there is no a gap over 5 minites between the rows regardless UID (i.e if there is a row with some timestamp then you need to exist the row with a timestamp within 5 minutes regardless its UID), or for each separate UID the gap must be not above 5 minutes?

Comment: Hello Akina, Yes the system receives ~7000 rows every 5 minutes, then does nothing for 5 minutes.  Also, I want to check for a gap regardless of the UID. Thank you.

Comment: The amount of rows per chunk is low. I think that you may use separate table which stores rows insertion timestamps, and trigger which inserts the timestamp of current inserted row into this separate table ignoring duplicates. Finally you have a table with distinct timestamps only, and checking the gap between consecutive timestamps is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` analytical function as follows:

```
select t.* from
(select t.*
       lag(Time_stamp) over (order by Time_stamp) as lg_ts
  from your_Table t)
where timestampdiff('minute',lg_ts,Time_stamp) > 5
```

Or you can also use the `not exists` as follows:

```
select t.* 
  from your_table t
 where not exists
       (select 1 from your_table tt
         where timestampdiff('minute',tt.Time_stamp,t.Time_stamp) <= 5)
   and t.Time_stamp <> (select min(tt.Time_stamp) from your_table tt)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lead()` or `lag()` is the right approach (depending on whether you want to see the row at the start or end of the gap).

For the time comparison, I recommend direct comparisons:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             lead(Time_stamp) over (partition by uid order by Time_stamp) as next_time_stamp
      from t
     ) t
where next_timestamp > time_stamp + interval 5 minute;
```

Note:  *exactly* 5 minutes seems unlikely.  You might want a fudge factor such as:

```
where next_timestamp > time_stamp + interval 5*60 + 10 second;
```

`timestampdiff()` counts the number of "boundaries" between two values.  So, the difference in minutes between 00:00:59 and 00:01:02 is `1`.  And the difference between 00:00:00 and 00:00:59 is `0`.

So, a difference of "5 minutes" could really be 4 minutes and 1 second or could be 5 minutes and 59 seconds.